# TabHost setIndicator - use layouts, not icons?

Tags: android, android-tabhost, android-selector

I'm creating tab this way:

```
TabSpec tab = tabHost.newTabSpec("Tab1").setIndicator("Tab1",res.getDrawable(R.drawable.tab1_selector));
```

and this is my selector:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:id="@+id/tab3Selector">

    <item android:drawable="@drawable/icon_pressed" android:state_selected="true"/>
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/icon_unpressed"/>

</selector>
```

where **icon_pressed** and **icon_unpressed** are just **icons** (png). This works fine. However, I would like to use instead of setting icon and title to set just layout (where I can set my title+icon however I want). SO I tried this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:id="@+id/tab3Selector">    
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/layout_pressed" android:state_selected="true"/>
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/layout_unpressed"/>    
</selector>
```

where **layout_pressed** and **layout_unpressed** are layouts like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:src="@drawable/icon_pressed" 
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"/>

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_marginLeft="35dp"
        android:textColor="@color/red"
        android:textSize="@dimen/fontSmall"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

And strangely I on runtime my app throws error:

```
    89): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
02-22 11:22:40.422: E/AndroidRuntime(9089): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo {com.test.myapp/com.test.myapp.activities.TabsActivity}: android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: File res/drawable-hdpi/tab3_selector.xml from drawable resource ID #0x7f020010
02-22 11:22:40.422: E/AndroidRuntime(9089):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2185)
02-22 11:22:40.422: E/AndroidRuntime(9089):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2210)
02-22 11:22:40.422: E/AndroidRuntime(9089):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:142)
02-22 11:22:40.422: E/AndroidRuntime(9089):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1208)
02-22 11:22:40.422: E/AndroidRuntime(9089):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
02-22 11:22:40.422: E/AndroidRuntime(9089):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
02-22 11:22:40.422: E/AndroidRuntime(9089):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4931)
02-22 11:22:40.422: E/AndroidRuntime(9089):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
02-22 11:22:40.422: E/AndroidRuntime(9089):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
02-22 11:22:40.422: E/AndroidRuntime(9089):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:791)
02-22 11:22:40.422: E/AndroidRuntime(9089):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:558)
02-22 11:22:40.422: E/AndroidRuntime(9089):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
02-22 11:22:40.422: E/AndroidRuntime(9089): Caused by: android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: File res/drawable-hdpi/tab1_selector.xml from drawable resource ID #0x7f020010
02-22 11:22:40.422: E/AndroidRuntime(9089):     at android.content.res.Resources.loadDrawable(Resources.java:1947)
02-22 11:22:40.422: E/AndroidRuntime(9089):     at android.content.res.Resources.getDrawable(Resources.java:659)
02-22 11:22:40.422: E/AndroidRuntime(9089):     at com.test.myapp.activities.TabsActivity.onCreate(TabsActivity.java:39)
02-22 11:22:40.422: E/AndroidRuntime(9089):     at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5008)
02-22 11:22:40.422: E/AndroidRuntime(9089):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1079)
02-22 11:22:40.422: E/AndroidRuntime(9089):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2139)
02-22 11:22:40.422: E/AndroidRuntime(9089):     ... 11 more
02-22 11:22:40.422: E/AndroidRuntime(9089): Caused by: android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: File res/drawable-
hdpi/layout_pressed.xml from drawable resource ID #0x7f020016
02-22 11:22:40.422: E/AndroidRuntime(9089):     at android.content.res.Resources.loadDrawable(Resources.java:1947)
02-22 11:22:40.422: E/AndroidRuntime(9089):     at android.content.res.Resources.getDrawable(Resources.java:659)
02-22 11:22:40.422: E/AndroidRuntime(9089):     at android.graphics.drawable.StateListDrawable.inflate(StateListDrawable.java:173)
02-22 11:22:40.422: E/AndroidRuntime(9089):     at android.graphics.drawable.Drawable.createFromXmlInner(Drawable.java:881)
02-22 11:22:40.422: E/AndroidRuntime(9089):     at android.graphics.drawable.Drawable.createFromXml(Drawable.java:818)
02-22 11:22:40.422: E/AndroidRuntime(9089):     at android.content.res.Resources.loadDrawable(Resources.java:1944)
02-22 11:22:40.422: E/AndroidRuntime(9089):     ... 16 more
02-22 11:22:40.422: E/AndroidRuntime(9089): Caused by: org.xmlpull.v1.XmlPullParserException: Binary XML file line #2: invalid drawable tag RelativeLayout
02-22 11:22:40.422: E/AndroidRuntime(9089):     at android.graphics.drawable.Drawable.createFromXmlInner(Drawable.java:877)
02-22 11:22:40.422: E/AndroidRuntime(9089):     at android.graphics.drawable.Drawable.createFromXml(Drawable.java:818)
02-22 11:22:40.422: E/AndroidRuntime(9089):     at android.content.res.Resources.loadDrawable(Resources.java:1944)
02-22 11:22:40.422: E/AndroidRuntime(9089):     ... 21 more
```

What does it mean, I can't use in TabHost tabs setIndicator(selector with layouts)?

Comment: You have Resources$NotFoundException at File res/drawable-hdpi/layout_pressed.xml check you have all resources you use at this layout - icon, color, dimension

Comment: your logcat show that the tab1_selector.xml not found in res/drawable-hdpi/tab1_selector.xml folder

Comment: you can move the tab1_selector.xml file into drawable-hdpi folder for testing

Comment: all files (selector, icons, layouts which used in selectors) are in drawable/hdpi folder. Checked twice...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

well, it's probably not my fault, but android issue. Look at my selector:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:id="@+id/tab3Selector">

    <!-- Layouts (in drawable folder) - don't work !!!  -->

    <item android:drawable="@drawable/pressed_layout" android:state_selected="true"/>
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/unpressed_layout" android:state_selected="false"/>

    <!-- Icons (in drawable folder) - work !!!  -->

<!--<item android:drawable="@drawable/pressed_icon" android:state_selected="true"/> -->
<!--<item android:drawable="@drawable/unpressed_icon"/> -->

</selector>
```

Looks like in TabHost setIndicator method simple can;t be selector with layouts, but can be selector with icons...

Answer (score 0):

1. First put your all selector.xml files in res/drawable folder

Replace

```
TabSpec tab = tabHost.newTabSpec("Tab1").setIndicator("Tab1",res.getDrawable(R.drawable.tab1_selector));
```

With

```
TabSpec tab = tabHost.newTabSpec("Tab1").setIndicator("Tab1",getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.tab1_selector));
```

Comment: well, of course res is local variable: res = getResources() ;) That;'s not problem. And all my selectors are in drawable dir, also all used layout in selectors...

Answer (score 0):

`Caused by: android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: File res/drawable-hdpi/tab1_selector.xml from drawable resource ID #0x7f020010`

`Caused by: android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: File res/drawable-hdpi/layout_pressed.xml from drawable resource ID #0x7f020010`

Stacktrace shows that Android system cannot find some of the resources in their specified folders. Have you provided the resorces in appropriate folders.

Answer (score 0):

I know this is old, but according to the `TabHost` API page quick-linked [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TabHost.TabSpec.html), if you want to do anything with layouts, use the `setIndicator(View view)` instead of the `setIndicator(CharSequence label, Drawable icon)` version.

Based off of the [Drawable API](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/drawable/Drawable.html), a `layout` cannot be a`Drawable`. It is like trying to make an orange become an apple. Both are fruit, just like both a `layout` and an `icon` are something you see as something potentially more than just text. However, they are still different and are handled differently.